# Rail stat generator with Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, statistics, analytics, web-analytics-tools

It is possible to use Rail_stat_generator(https://github.com/lmanolov/railstat) with Ruby on Rails 3? What should I do to install it and make it work? If it is not possible, what any open source analytics apps would you suggest?

Answer (score 0):

I think that you may run into problems using that in Rails 3, seems kinda outdated.

I would highly recommend using an external tool, like awstats for that job.

http://awstats.sourceforge.net/